# Java collection object declaration

Tags: java

`List<Interval<Integer>> x = new LinkedList<Interval<Integer>>()`

I'm not sure if I understand the above statement. Is it List with interval object that has integer data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List` holds a bunch of `Interval` objects that are of type `Integer`